# Python CSV string slicing issue

Tags: python, string, email, csv

I am Python beginning and I am trying to clean data in a CSV file.

I have a list of emails, however some fields have multiple emails like this:

```
companyNameA | shana@example.com;privacy@example.com;info@example.com | date joined
```

I do not understand how to duplicate the row for each email. The other data should stay same but the email should be different so like this:

```
companyNameA | shana@example.com | date joined
companyNameA | privacy@example.com | date joined
companyNameA | info@example.com | date joined
```

I have tried this, but it does not work:

```
f = open('data_file.csv')
csv_f = csv.reader(f)

for row in csv_f:
    email = row[1]
    single_email = email.rsplit(';', 1)[0]
```

Comment: Are you just trying to print this? Or are you trying to restructure it and write it back out to file?

Comment: Well that's a good start, but what did you actually try to modify your csv file?

Answer (score 1):

You need read from one csv line by line and write to another one in multiple lines in case of more no. of emails in email column.

```
fin = open('data_file.csv')
fout = open('out_data_file.csv', 'w')

csv_fin = csv.reader(fin)
csv_fout = csv.writer(fout)

for row in csv_fin:
    emails = row[1].split(';')
    if len(emails) > 1:
        for e in emails:
            csv_fout.writerow((row[0], e, row[2]))
    else:
       csv_fout.writerow(row)
```

Hope this is what you are expecting.

Answer (score 1):

To create a row for each email address, you first need to read each row in from the input CSV file. This is done using a CSV reader object with the delimiter set to be your `|` character. You can then use the `writerows()` function to write multiple rows in one go, one for each email address found by splitting the second column entry on the `;` character.

In this example, it is done using a generator. For each email address, a row is created holding the first column from the input row, the current email address and the last column from the entry row. The `writerows()` function continues working until all emails have been read in (which can also be just 1).

Lastly, to preserve your extra spaces in the output, first `strip()` is used on the current email address to remove any possible existing spaces, and `format()` is used to ensure a space is added before and after the email address.

```
import csv    

with open('input.csv', 'rb') as f_input, open('output.csv', 'wb') as f_output:
    csv_input = csv.reader(f_input, delimiter='|')
    csv_output = csv.writer(f_output, delimiter='|')

    for row in csv_input:
        csv_output.writerows([row[0], ' {} '.format(email.strip()), row[2]] for email in row[1].split(';'))
```

Note, Python's CSV module does not allow the delimiter to be multiple characters.

Answer (score 0):

With `single_email = email.rsplit(';', 1)[0]` You're getting only one mail address. You could split second column, and go through them in loop, something like this:

```
f = open('data_file.csv')
csv_f = csv.reader(f)

for row in csv_f:
    email = row[1]
    for mail_addr in email.split(';'):
        do_something()
```